# Atualizar pagina ao inserir dados no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho um banco de dados com uma tabela conversas,ela possui os seguintes atributos:

1. transmissor
2. receptor
3. hora_msg
4. mensagem
5. id

Preciso que assim que um usuário manda uma mensagem ,atualize a pagina do receptor,tentei fazendo o seguinte

```
$sql         = "SELECT * FROM conversas WHERE transmissor LIKE '$transmissor' AND receptor LIKE '$receptor' OR receptor LIKE '$transmissor' AND transmissor LIKE '$receptor'";
        $result      = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        echo "<table><thead></thead>
                <tbody>";
        if($linhas = mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
            $teste = mysqli_affected_rows($connect);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $mensagem  = $row['mensagem'];
                $rec       = $row['receptor'];
                $hora      = $row['hora_msg'];
                $id        = $row['id'];
                $hora      = preg_replace('/:00.0000/',"",$hora);
                $ultimaMsg = strtotime($hora);
                $classe    = "";
                $result2   = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
                while($l = mysqli_fetch_array($result2) > 0){
                    $hora2  = $l['hora_msg'];
                    $hora2  = preg_replace('/:00.0000/',"",$hora2);
                    $ultMsg = strtotime($hora2);
                    if($ultMsg > $ultimaMsg){
                        header("Refresh: 0; url = cnv.php");
                    }

                }
                echo "<div class='invisivel'>$id</div>";
                if($rec === $transmissor)$classe = 'receptor';
                else $classe = 'transmissor';
                $mensagem = base64_decode($mensagem);

                if(preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$mensagem))
                     echo "<tr class='sms'><td><div class=$classe><div class='hora'>$hora</div><a href='$mensagem' target='blank'>$mensagem</a></div></td></tr>";
                else     
                     echo "<tr class='sms'><td><div class=$classe><div class='hora'>$hora</div>$mensagem </div></td></tr>";
            }
            echo "</tbody>
                    </table>";

            }
```

Mas não obtive o resultado esperado,o que preciso é que assim que for inserido algo no banco de dados a pagina seja atualizada.

Comment: Amigo, já ouviu falar em Nodejs; sem dúvida, esse formato não é indicado para resolver esse tipo de problema

Comment: Sim,conheço,mas como ficaria com o nodejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está tentando atingir um objetivo através de um caminho inadequado, quando uma mensagem for enviada, o script que é carregado é apenas para o usuário que enviou a mensagem (a requisição é apenas de um usuário).

Quando faz refresh com o PHP você está enviando um cabeçalho apenas para esse usuário que enviou a mensagem. Dessa forma, apenas o transmissor "ganha" o refresh.

O que deve estar buscando é o caminho inverso de uma requisição HTTP "comum", ao invés do cliente (browser) disparar a requisição, o servidor vai enviar uma requisição para os browser de um ou mais receptores. Para tal, utilize websockets!

Socket.io é uma boa ferramenta para isso, mas não é PHP e sim NodeJS.

Comment: Entendi,agradeço

Comment: Se está satisfeito com a resposta, marque que ela respondeu sua pergunta, mas pode esperar caso alguém mais responda e assim ter outras visões para o seu problema ;)

Comment: Vou esperar alguém mais,mas após isso marco como respondida ,obrigado